# Help Needed! GWT Error

Tags: gwt

I am a beginner in GWT. I'm trying a first application with GWT for almost 6 hours. I am following a tutorial and everything should go fine. But I dont know what problem I am getting with service def target. Please can someone help me, it concerns very basic rpc. I am just trying to bring a hello string from the server and display it at the client for the sake of knowing the basics of rpc

you can find the eclipse file i coded uploaded at http://noorsolution.zxq.net/Hi.zip
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please be more specific: Post the complete stack trace you're getting. Is is a runtime error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your actual exception, So it will better to understand.

There is no any service interface in your application.In gwt there must be interface implementing Remote Service.
I suggest you to make a simple application form gwt, which will give you all basically related classes.

May this will help you.

Comment: OK, implementing the interfaces and the implementation class is ok, I am getting diffuculties to set the service def target and the serverlet in the xml file